# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' with redirect(reverse) in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

my django app has a form view for submitting information that creates a new post, after which it should redirect to a thank you page.

```
def submit(request, slug):
    account = get_object_or_404(Account, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
       # process the data and post form as JSON 
       ret = create_or_edit_post(request, account, post=None, duplicate=False)
       if isinstance(ret, HttpResponseRedirect):
          post = account.posts.latest('id')
          # handle post info and post creation

          return redirect(reverse('post-submit-ty', kwargs={'slug': account.slug}))
       return ret

    context = { "account": account }

    return render(request, 'submit.html', context)
```

since the redirect(reverse(...)) returns a tuple, this throws:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 131, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 325, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 32, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
```

since I need to pass `slug` kwarg (as a tuple) and redirect to the thank you page but it's looking for an http response is there a way to handle this with `redirect(reverse)` or `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse)`? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can pass a view name with arguments and `redirect` is gonna do internally a `reverse`.

Try this, `redirect('post-submit-ty',slug=account.slug)`.

[Django Shourtcuts redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)